# Querying a Table with two ID Fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a table called `Actions` with 2 identifiers: `Ref` & `Status`
Status can be any one of the following: `new`, `done`

```
  Ref  |  Status  |  Date   
  ---------------------------------- 
   1   |   new    | 10/31/2018   
   1   |   done   | 10/31/2018
   2   |   new    | 10/31/2018
```

I'd like to query only the actions that are `new` but not `done`. In this example, the query would only return the 3rd row of the table.

Here's what I tried so far, but I only get the action that have been put to status `done`:

```
SELECT [2].[project title], [2].ref, [2].[Date] As [Creation Date]
    FROM (SELECT * From T_ACTIONS Where status = "New") AS [1],  
         (SELECT * From T_ACTIONS Where status = "Done") AS [2]
    WHERE [1].[Project Title] = [Insert a valid : Project Title]
    AND [1].[REF] = [2].[Ref]
```

I'm using Access 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Actions a
WHERE Status = 'new' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Actions a1 WHERE a1.REF = a.REF AND a1.Status = 'Done');
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot, I've been struggling with this query for some time now

Answer (score 3):

You could `LEFT JOIN` your Actions table to a nested `SELECT` query retrieving all references with status `Done`, with a test for records with no corresponding record in the nested query, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM 
    Actions a LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.Ref FROM Actions b WHERE b.Status = 'Done') t
    ON a.Ref = t.Ref
WHERE
    a.Status = 'New' AND t.Ref IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method uses aggregation:

```
select ref
from actions
where status in ('new', 'done')
group by ref
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'new';
```